# (typescript) how do i open a modal on click of a button? additionally, how do i pass in parameters to be shown inside this modal?

Tags: typescript, modal-dialog

context: i have a client dashboard page that shows all my client data and gives me the option to edit and delete and i already have a working api to update client data. on click of the edit button, i want a modal to pop up with the respective client details on it inside text field's placeholder. it should look something like this.

on click of this button in red,
[image]

modal will show up with client details

[image]

Here is what I have tried. In my web export, I set an empty div and display as none, this will be my modal.

```
export default async function ClientDashboardPage() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen p-4 sm:ml-64">
      <div className="flex flex-col">
        <h1 style={{ fontSize: "2rem", fontWeight: "bold", marginBottom: "1rem" }}>Client Dashboard</h1>
        <DisplayClientData />
        <div id="updateClientModal" style={{ display: "none" }}></div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

showUpdateClientModal function gets all the client details and passes it into the inner HTML of the empty div in ClientDashboard Page and then sets the display to visible.

```
const updateClientModal = document.getElementById("updateClientModal");

async function showUpdateClientModal(userId: string, email: string, contactNumber: string, country: string, company: string, jobTitle: string, companyAddress: string, postalCode: string) {
  updateClientModal.innerHTML = `
<form onsubmit="updateClient()">
    <div>
        <label>
            User ID
        </label><br>
        <input id="userIdInput" type="text" placeholder="${userId}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Email
        </label><br>
        <input id="emailInput" type="text" placeholder="${email}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Contact Number
        </label><br>
        <input id="contactNumberInput" type="text" placeholder="${contactNumber}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Country
        </label><br>
        <input id="countryInput" type="text" placeholder="${country}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Company
        </label><br>
        <input id="companyInput" type="text" placeholder="${company}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Job Title
        </label><br>
        <input id="jobTitleInput" type="text" placeholder="${jobTitle}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Company Address
        </label><br>
        <input id="companyAddressInput" type="text" placeholder="${companyAddress}" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Postal Code
        </label><br>
        <input id="postalCodeInput" type="text" placeholder="${postalCode}" />
    </div>
    <button onclick="closeModal()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
  `;

  updateClientModal.style.display = "block";
}

// Close modal after cancel button press
function closeModal() {
updateClientModal.style.display = 'none';
}
```

Edit button, onclick, pass all the client details into showUpdateClientModal function

```
<button onClick={() => showUpdateClientModal(client.UserId, client.Email, client.ContactNumber, client.Country, client.Company, client.JobTitle, client.CompanyAddress, client.PostalCode)}>
```

After some debugging, my showUpdateClientModal function was able to receive all the client data as I was able to console log all of it. Also, I keep receiving this error that 'updateClientModal' is possibly 'null'.